# Understanding meteorjs scope by adding the autotags library?

Tags: javascript, meteor, closures, scope

I'm trying to experiment with [this library](https://code.google.com/p/autotags/ in meteor).

First, when I tried to install all the individual javascript files  to client/compatibility folder, I get an error message when calling AUTOTAGS from the constants js file:

```
AUTOTAGS = { ... } // autotags-js-core.js
AUTOTAGS.TAG_CONSTANTS = [ 'news','research','favourite' ]; // autotags-js-constants.js
```

It kept saying that AUTOTAGS was undefined. I deduced from reading about global scope that any external library with VAR that you want to have global scope, put it under compatibility.

If that's correct, then why isnt the scope global when putting all individual files under lib/external? AUTOTAGS = {..} without var means its available to entire application right?

Instead, I got the scope to work by combining all the javascript files in one single js file under lib/external. I thought I understood, but it gets worse.

Within a single js file - any function that begins with a closure is local to that FILE, and not global scope, whilst any function assigned to variable name makes it a global variable?

```
function(something() { ... } ) // closure, local
generateTags = function() { ... } // global scope?
var generateTags = function() { .... } // is this local or global?
```

If the var generateTags function is local, then putting it under client/compatibility will make it global? Lastly! - I get the vague notion that I should define global variables under lib/environment.js from here - https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files, is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two questions here. One is about how the scope works in **javascript**, the other about integrating the **autotags** library into a meteor project. Since the answer for the first one should be relatively easy to find somewhere else, I'll only try to answer the second question.

The reason you are getting this "undefined" error is not a scope problem but it is somehow related to the order in which the files are loaded into your meteor app. Namely, `autotags-js-constants.js` comes before `autotag-js-core.js` because **constants** precedes **core** in the alphabetic ordering. In consequence, the `AUTOTAGS` variable is not defined at the point when the `autotags-js-constants.js` file is being parsed.

One simple way to overcome this issue is to rename your files, so as to enforce the right loading order. Another way is to use a tool that will enable you to define dependencies between files. If you are interested please take a look at [require](https://github.com/apendua/require) project, which is basically a lightweight and meteor friendly implementation of the core **requirejs** features.

However, probably the best solution is to create a custom smart package. It would allow you to explicitly define the order in which the files should be loaded. Just take a look on some existing smart packages to get the idea on how this should be implemented. I would also recommend using [meteorite](http://oortcloud.github.io/meteorite/) to manage your custom smart packages.